# multiple subdomains, service worker cache and push

Tags: caching, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a web application that uses many subdomains as the main page for each -- subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com, ...  Each page is unique (a separate web app) , but uses similar html and js source generated server-side (from common php/db) for the specific subdomain.

I would now like to add two features: caching (for offline viewing) and push notifications.  I would like the push notification approval/denial to be unique for **each** subdomain.  In other words, denying push for subdomain1 would not deny it for other subdomains.  So it seems I can use a service worker for each subdomain.

However, I am concerned that the common JS and CSS elements (like JQuery) will be cached in each subdomain cache.  This seems quite inefficient and wasteful.

If I redirect subdomainX.example.com to something like example.com/?SD=X, I can have a single Service Worker for all the pages and thus a common cache.  However, now the Push Notification approval/denial would be for all subdomains - not individually as I want.

Is there any way to have separate push notification approval/denial and a common cache?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: what build tool are you using? there should be fine-grained control over content of multiple , named caches. So the JQuery stuff goes in a higher level, named cache and the subdomain specific stuff goes into a more granular cache. The SW would be tasked with checking both caches. Workbox example : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/574   there are multiple cache names in example

Comment: But it will not apply cross-origin (cross-domain). I'm afraid [Cross-origin Service Worker via Foreign Fetch](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/foreign-fetch) (once it's available) will be the only solution here.

Comment: @NOtherDev: yes saw that.  Is it even possible if I host all the cacheable content??  Again, two different SWs would need to share a common cache.

Comment: @RobertRowntree no build tool. Straight JS for the Service Workers (although they are generated via PHP - for some subdomain specifics). How would two different Service Workers put and get from the same cache? Seems to me a SW can only access its own cache(s).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/0e1cfeeccad94edc2f0985a15adefe54   shows multiple routes and various caches from within same SW. these are examples using 'workbox'

Comment: @RobertRowntree TY, but those are all from the same SW.  Can two two *different* SWs running at the same time share a common cache?

Comment: related on multiple service workers ... https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/921